# Method does not search in database?

Tags: android, sqlite, methods, parameters

Since morning, I've been trying to figure it out a problem that occured me today, and now, close to midnight I found out the problem.. I have 2 methods in a database, one for registering new users and one for login management purposes. Both use the same parameters:

1- user class, 2- var for user class.

The login management gets text from 2 edittexts and compare their values with database ( something like username/password ) and the other have the basic variables.getVariables() -> insert(table,null,variables).

When I call registra_usuario method, translated for register_user it proceeds like it inserted the info into database. But, when I use the second method busca_acesso (search_access) it gives me an OutofBounds error

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
```

Does this mean that the database has nothing inside TABLE_USER? Because cursor has a size of 0?

These are my two methods:

```
public boolean registra_usuario(user user){ <- ***THIS ONE SAYS IT'S NEVER USED***
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    try{
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_ENTRY_ID, user.getId());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_USERNAME, user.getUsername());
        values.put(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD, user.getPassword());
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT      , user.getCreated_at());
        db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);

        CharSequence text = "Usuário Cadastrado!!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(null, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        return true;
    }catch (Exception e){
        db.close();
        return false;
    }
}

UPDATED METHOD
public boolean busca_acesso(user user){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String [] tabela_user = new String[]{"usuaid","username","password"};
    String [] whereargs   = new String[]{user.getUsername()};
    String compare_user = projeto_db.COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ?";

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_USER, tabela_user, compare_user, whereargs, null, null, null );
    int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.getString(index).equals(user.getPassword())){
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    if(cursor.getString(index).equals(user.getPassword())) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }}

final projeto_db db = new projeto_db(this);

            user user = new user(); ***MAIN_ACTIVITY
            user.setUsername(username_login);
            user.setPassword(password_login);
            db.busca_acesso(user);



            user user = new user(); ***DIFFERENT ACTIVITY
            user.setId();
            user.setUsername(editText_username.getText().toString());
            user.setPassword(editText_password.getText().toString());
            user.setCreated_at(getDateTime());
            db.registra_usuario(user);
```

Both are being called inside onCreate from class and from onClick of Button.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't use `user` anywhere in the `registra_usuario()` method. Did you mean to use `user` instead of `add_usuario`?

Comment: Yeah. I just found out about that. Beginner's mistake haha. But thanks you for noticing. You can make an answer if you want. I'll mark it.

Comment: No problem. It's cool. You can just delete this one, if you want. Otherwise, I'm just gonna vote to close it as a simple mistake.

Comment: @Mike M. I guess we celebrated a little bit too soon... It's still not inserting data to the database as it should...

Comment: Well, that's not really what your question asks. There aren't any answers posted yet, so you could quickly [edit] it to change the focus, but you need to make sure to explain the actual problem, and provide enough info to diagnose it.

Comment: Done. I updated my question

Comment: I think the problem `projeto_db.COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD + " = ?"` but the argument passed is `user.getUsername()`. Therefore no user is found. Also, you should use `curosr.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)` to get the index then use `getString`. Because you are querying three column, and password are not in the first column.

Comment: @Joshua I changed the projeto_db._password to _username, put `cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD)` and changed the value from the getString to a `int variable = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_USER_PASSWORD)`. Is this correct? Still keep getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException Index -1 requested, with a size of 0... D:

Comment: How about passing all null parameters except the table name? It will return all columns and all values. Check if you have anything in the database.

Comment: @Joshua Okay. Now we're getting somewhere... `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 10` the table is being fed.

Comment: Try `cursor.moveToFirst()`  instead of `cursor != null`

Comment: I was wondering about it. Do I need to use a repeat loop in order to go through the entire table? like `while(!cursor.getString(index).equals(user.getPassword())){ cursor.moveToNext();  }`

Comment: No, I assume the user name is unique. There should be only 1 row return.
If this solved your problems, I can write you a detailed answer rather than pasting code in the comment.

Comment: Please do. I'llmark it as the answer. There's still something wrong regarding my cursor, but I'll find out myself. Appreciate your help.